# adding variables/types to a typing environment

Tags: functional-programming, inference, formal-languages, formal-semantics

I have an environment which contains a set of tokens that I have already come across; when I look at a new token I want to add that token to the current environment. Basically I want to express a set-union operation on the environment that I perform parsing in.

something like Γ' = {Γ , x}

and 
if I want to delete the variable 'x' (remove x from the environment)

Γ' = Γ - x if x ∈ Γ .

What is the proper way to write these two formalisms. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to implement your environment as some data structure that supports insert, delete and search, and pass that data structure to your parser. I imagine in your parser, you would look at the current token, does the appropriate update to the environment, then recursively call the parser on the next token then pass in the *updated* environment.

Which particular data structure to use is up to you, binary search tree or its variants would do fine, or you can just use Haskell's built-in list type if you don't care about performance.

EDIT: To write down this process formally, you can borrow from type rules and how they are written, here is a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_rule). For example, we can denote that a program is successfully parsed by `Γ ⊢ program:OK` (I'm not sure if you want to deal with actual types here). Then, to add a token into the environment, you can write

```
    Γ,id ⊢ program:OK
-------------------------
  Γ ⊢ add id, program:OK
```

To remove a token, you can write

```
        Γ ⊢ program:OK
------------------------------
  Γ,id ⊢ remove id, program:OK
```

Comment: I am only interested in writing formal rules, not the implementation.

Comment: @AdityaKumar Sorry I saw your haskell tag and assume it's a question about implementation. Are you trying to write type rules or something similar to type rules?

Comment: yes, I want something similar. but there is no type involved. just tokens.

Comment: so how do i specify the semantics of `add` and `remove`. can i just describe their meaning.

Comment: @AdityaKumar They are part of your language, if you are parsing C, it would be `Γ ⊢ int foo, program:OK` if `Γ, foo ⊢ program:OK`, so yes you can just describe them.